# Cast Varchar as Integer in propel for addAscendingOrderByColumn

Tags: symfony1, integer, sql-order-by, propel, varchar

I have a method in order to get data out of a database for a propel-based symfony-1.1 project.

Now the use-case arrived to store an integer into a `varchar` field, which results in a wrong order, e.g. `{1, 17, 5}`, and not the numeric one I was expecting, i.e. `{1, 5, 17}`.

I know that one way would be to redesign my `schema.yml`, but this is not an option. I was wondering if there is a way to cast said `varchar` field as an integer without harming the propel-approach.

This is the sorting function:

```
public static function getFooData($column = 'FooPeer::ID', $orderBy = 'asc') {
    //FIXME: Sort varchar fields as integer, needed for FooPeer::REQUESTS

    $c = new Criteria();

    if ($orderBy == 'asc') {
        $c->addAscendingOrderByColumn($column);
    } else {
        $c->addDescendingOrderByColumn($column);
    }

    return FooPeer::doSelect($c);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn('CAST('.$column.' AS UNSIGNED)');
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works. I would upvote you if I only could ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just for interest, you could also have written a view for this, and build your model on top of the view rather than the table. Assuming you're writing to the table with Propel, this solution requires the platform to support writable views (I'm not sure they all do, but perhaps that assumption is out of date).

This is often a good/quick technique where you're not sure how to do something in Propel, or where it is really awkward. It's saved me a few times, even though it's not every purist's cup of tea.